# How to add a comma to a Mailgun from field for outbound emails?

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I am using the [mailgun npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js) package put out by mailgun.

I would like the `from` field to have a comma when displaying the "name" in the users email.

`Excited, User <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>` but its turns into `User <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>`

The from name in the email is `User` instead of `Excited, User`

Below is my code: (notice the comma in the `from` field)

```
mg.messages.create('sandbox-123.mailgun.org', {
    from: "Excited, User <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>",
    to: ["test@example.com"],
    subject: "Hello",
    text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
    html: "<h1>Testing some Mailgun awesomness!</h1>"
  })
  .then(msg => console.log(msg)) // logs response data 
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); // logs any error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the name portion of the address in double quotes, like this:

`from: '"Excited, User" <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>',`

Here's the site I'm using for reference: http://mailformat.dan.info/headers/from.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is..

`'=?UTF-8?q?Excited=2C_User?= <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>'`

This is was the answer I received from Mailgun.

@Freyday - Your answer is wayyyy cleaner and working perfectly! Thanks :)